# angular draggable and sortable divs without ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, drag-and-drop

On my page I have 4 different divs. Each of them has own jstree with data from external json files.

```
   <div  class="panel frame">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingCorporate">
                            <p class="panel-title" align="center">
                                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseCorporate" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseCorporate">
                                    Corporate Frame   <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseCorporate" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingCorporate">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <js-tree tree-data="json" tree-src="data-tree/corporate.json"
                                         tree-plugins="contextmenu,dnd,types,wholerow,search,state"
                                         tree-events="changed:callback;"></js-tree>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div  class="panel frame">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingClinical">
                        <p class="panel-title panel-primary" align="center">
                            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseClinical" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseClinical">
                                Clinical Hierarchy Frame   <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
                            </a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseClinical" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingClinical">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <js-tree tree-data="json" tree-src="data-tree/clinical.json"
                                     tree-plugins="contextmenu,dnd,types,wholerow,search,state"
                                     tree-events="changed:callback;"></js-tree>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div  class="panel frame">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingStudy">
                        <p class="panel-title" align="center">
                            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseStudy" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseStudy">
                                Study Frame   <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
                            </a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseStudy" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingStudy">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <js-tree tree-data="json" tree-src="data-tree/study.json"
                                     tree-plugins="contextmenu,dnd,types,wholerow,search,state"
                                     tree-events="changed:callback;"></js-tree>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div  class="panel frame">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingIndustry">
                        <p class="panel-title" align="center">
                            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseIndustry" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseIndustry">
                                Industry Frame   <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
                            </a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseIndustry" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingIndustry">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <js-tree tree-data="json" tree-src="data-tree/industry.json"
                                     tree-plugins="contextmenu,dnd,types,wholerow,search,state"
                                     tree-events="changed:callback;"></js-tree>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I need to drag and drop this divs. The [example](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable/blob/master/example-reorder.html) of ngDraggable directive is pretty close what I want to do, but it's still require ng-repeat. So my question is there any way to make draggable and sortable list of 4 different divs without ng-repeat?

Comment: This drag and drop functionality based on the ability to change the order of the divs. In other words, when you drop a `div` the `ng-repeat` recreate them all that's how he can reorder those. If you don't use `ng-repeat` you have no way to reorder them. You can add your own code to recreate those divs but it's risky to play with the DOM when you use Angular.

Comment: @MoshFeu how I've understood,  in my case no way to do it, right? of course I can set for each div own view and then to set it into object inside controller  and then represent it on page thru ng-repeat but I thought about easy way.

Comment: It's possible but no recommend..

Comment: @MoshFeu got it, thank you for explanation

Comment: My pleasure :-)  Good luck.